# Bootstrap glyphicons not working in .Netcore 3.1

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In converting a project from .netcore 2.1 to 3.1, I cannot get the Bootstrap glyphicon to work.  To test this I created a Visual Studio (Version 16.6.2) .Netcore 3.1 web project using the defaults and MVC.  I then changed just the index.cshtml view as below.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
        <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
        <p>Envelope icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></p>

    </div>
```

Nothing displays.  Anybody else seeing this?

Comment: This has got nothing to do with .NET Core. Bootstrap 4 doesn't have glyphicons.

Comment: Mmm, anyway to get the same functionality in .Netcore 3.1

Comment: @NHLIVES this is not related to .net core. It related to html and css only